# Set doc = IE.document returns Automation Error

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, methods

I'm trying to populate this form (https://help.grab.com/merchant/vi-vn/360027910731-DJang-ky-tham-gia-chuong-trinh-khuyen-mai-cung-GrabFood) with a set of excel data, filling each field of the form with respective column in Excel. I came across several tutorials on StackOverflow and Youtube on using VBA to open IE, navigate and fill in text box, from which I wrote these codes.

The problem comes when I run this code and Excel returns an error message box saying

> Run-time Error '-2147467259 (80004005) Automation Error Unspecified Error.

I am too amateur to diagnose these codes that run perfectly on various videos on Youtube. Hope you guys can help me :)

```
Sub IE()

    Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = IE.document    //The error I mentioned above is in this line

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://help.grab.com/merchant/vi-vn/360027910731-DJang-ky-tham-gia-chuong-trinh-khuyen-mai-cung-GrabFood"

    Do While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    For Each ele In IE.document.getElementsByClassName("ant-radio-input")
        If ele.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") Then ele.Click: Exit For
    Next

    doc.getElementById("phone").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
    doc.getElementById("email").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value

    IE.Quit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the ie.document until after you have created the IE instance and the document is loaded.

```
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://help.grab.com/merchant/vi-vn/360027910731-DJang-ky-tham-gia-chuong-trinh-khuyen-mai-cung-GrabFood"
While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4:DoEvents:Wend
Set doc = IE.document
```

Comment: Did you try this?